# Error Segmentation fault (core dumped) in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wamp, windows

I have installed **Magento 2** in my Windows Local Machine using **WAMP 3.0.4**. I tried making a simple "Hello World" module. But, when I tried to run the module, I get the following error:

> Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
>
> The following modules are outdated:
>
> Censere_HelloWorld schema: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
> Censere_HelloWorld data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0

But when I tried to run the command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** in **Cygwin**, it throws me the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What could I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're running via WAMP, make sure you are calling the proper php version binary. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192049/magento-commands-segmentation-fault-core-dumped?rq=1 A segment fault would most likely be environment related.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases infinite recursion cause Segmentation fault. Try install xdebug  extension and run one more time.