# Magento Commands - Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: magento2, error, command-line, command

I receive the following error when running any of the magento commands in CL? Any ideas on how to resolve?

> Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for this message is infinite recursion.

Try to install xdebug extension (that allow limiting max stacks) and rerun commands

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It turned out that commands I was runnnig were for PHP7.1, and on server it was PHP7.3.

Once I ran them like `/usr/bin/php71` they were executed without problems.

Hope it helps to someone :)